# Jquery toggle only childens

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have this jquery code to toggle a submenu on click.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".widget .menu-item-has-children").click(function () {
        $(".widget .menu-item-has-children > .sub-menu").toggle();
    });
});
```

But this display all .sub-menu, not only clicked link children. How can i put "only do this to children" with jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.widget .menu-item-has-children').click(function () {
        // `this` refers to the current `.widget .menu-item-has-children`
        $(this).children('.sub-menu').toggle();
    });
});
```